# How to keep open modal login form after failed login attempt

Tags: jquery, html, laravel, authentication, modal-dialog

I have a form about auth-login. When i try to failed login attempt page was refreshing and modal form closing as you might guess. But i want to make still visible modal login form after the failed attempt.

This is the my blade page.

```
<div id="login-select-field" class="col-md-3 col-6 d-flex-center-align">
@if(Auth::guard('customer')->check())
    <div id="login-select-box" class="bg-white c-black d-none">
        <div>
            <form name="loginForm" action="#" method="POST">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                <h2 class="f-16 pt-3 pl-4 mb-3">Sn. {{ Auth::guard('customer')->user()->name }}</h2>
                <div class="checkboxes f-14">
                    <div class="sign-in-border">
                        <a href="{{ route('customer_reset_password') }}">{{__('growinemea.index.resetpass')}}</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sign-in-border">
                        <a href="{{ route('customer.logout') }}"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i>{{__('growinemea.auth.logout')}}</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    @else
</div>
```

When form was opened

```
bg-white c-black d-none
```

its returning

```
bg-white c-black d-block
::before
```

But changing this doesn't change smt. I tried some jquery codes for this but i failed. Because of me. I am not good at that. 
I am open any suggestion. Thanks in advance.

edit: Login Controller

```
    public function login(Request $request){


    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' =>  'required|email',
        'password'  =>  'required',
    ]);

    if (Auth::guard('customer')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password], $request->remember)) {
        return redirect()->intended(route('homepage'));
    }
    return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'));
}
```

edit2:

```
@if($errors->any())
<p>A</p>
@else
<p>B</p>
@endif
```

Comment: I suggest use ajax to submit form. Which can better handle modal and error

Comment: would you like to show your `controllers` code?

Comment: controller codes are normal. Just login, cookie, password match. Nothing about front-end or fail warnings.

Comment: @ChiragPatel post was edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code in your login method,

```
 public function login(Request $request){


    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' =>  'required|email',
        'password'  =>  'required',
    ]);

    if (Auth::guard('customer')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password], $request->remember)) {
        return redirect()->intended(route('homepage'));

        return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'));
    } else {
       return redirect('homepage')->with('error', 'Login Failed!');
    }

 }
```

After this, you have to define this in your modal before `<form>` tag

```
@if (session('error'))
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        {{ session('error') }}
    </div>
@endif
```

And if your modal is closed after request try this in your code to reopen modal ,

```
@if (session('error'))
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#modal').modal('open'); //include your model id
</script>
@endif
```

Try this and comment if you have any query.

Comment: I got the error in json format. So how can i transfer these errors to the page. Jquery needs that errors.

Comment: It's in the answer `@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            <li>{{ $errors }}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif` write this in your modal

Comment: you can direct show error on your modal by doing this.

Comment: After clicking submit button. Its going to homepage without errors. $errors= null. But return response()->json(...) got the errors. Errors need to go index page.

Comment: I am redirecting with this code line.
return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'));

Comment: so what do you want after clicking? want to redirect to homepage or at same page?

Comment: No sir, i can't tell myself. Your codes perfectly works. Modal is opening. But there is one problem. When i use return response json. I got the errors what i want. But when i use redirect()->back() errors are gone. And these jquery doesnt work. modal is not opening errors are not showing in the form. Because there is no error. But it must be.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168536/discussion-between-chirag-patel-and-ali-ozen).

Answer (score 0):

this might help.

```
@if ($errors->any())
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).on('load',function(){
        $('#your-modal-id').modal('show');
    });
</script>
@endif
```

Comment: i tried if($errors->any())  A else B endif
after failed attempt allways printing B. Cannot login in if.

Comment: No,not login function. The one that you did with `else`.

Comment: Edited again. As i said. its simple if else for testing $errors. But it can't catch the failed attempt.

Comment: where is your validation function? add that too.

Comment: or change `$this->validate($request, [` to `$request->validate([`